# Deleting a specific column from specific work sheet gives "Sub or Function not defined" compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete a specific column from a specific worksheet and I cannot figure out why this sub is giving me this error:

> Compile error: Sub or Function not defined

I have a different private sub that i have set up and call the same way and works fine, so I am thinking my syntax is off? (I'm level zero on vba )

Calling the Sub

```
Sub HideColumns()
   ...
   Call Del_Col_A
   ...
End Sub
```

The Sub

```
Private Sub Del_Col_A()

   Sheet("Sheet7").Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you spelled the name correctly? Also, a `Private` Sub can only be called wthin that same module.

Comment: I am calling from same module. By name, do you mean the name of the sheet or the name of the Sub when I call it?

Comment: I feel so stupid. I thought sheet 7 would work, but it needed the actual sheet name that is given... that was the issue there... If you post it as an answer I can mark it as the answer...

Comment: Why are you calling a different sub to delete a column?

Comment: I set the subs up like methods... on public sub like a main method, and private subs like methods to call.. I'm sure its the wrong way to do it, but...

Comment: Just seems unnecessary. At least you could add a parameter and use it to delete any column, not just A.

Comment: I only need it for this one particular instance of an issue with that column... Won't be using it anywhere else, but. yah. I could make the sub more dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `"Sheet7"` is actually your sheet name, so:

```
Sheets("your sheet name").Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
```

if its not `"Sheet7"`

Comment: The name was "Youth M" which is what I needed to place there. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have forgotten the 's' on the end of 'sheets'

```
Private Sub Del_Col_A()

  Sheets("Sheet7").Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that before, it gives me an error:
_Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range_

Comment: Have a look at your sheet name. Make sure that is exact.

Comment: @Alex Like Will said, also you can try `Sheets(7)` or `Worksheets(7)` or `Worksheets("Sheet7")` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7)`, etc...

Comment: Or just `Sheets("Sheet7").Columns(1).Delete`.